# Prove that if $f(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ then $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform

**The Question**: Prove that if $f(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ then $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$

**My Proof**: To prove that $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$, we need to show that the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is equal to $f(x)$ itself, that is,
$\hat{f}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-2 \pi i x t} d t=f(x)$.
Substituting $f(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ into the above formula, we obtain
$\hat{f}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2} e^{-2 \pi i x t} d t$.
Using the definition of the Fourier transform, we have
$\hat{f}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2} e^{-2 \pi i x t} d t=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi(t+i x)^2} e^{-\pi x^2} d t$.
Completing the square in the exponent of the integrand, we have
$\hat{f}(x)=e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi(t+i x)^2-\pi x^2+\pi x^2} d t$.
The exponent in the integral can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
-\pi(t+ix)^2 - \pi x^2 + \pi x^2 &= -\pi (t^2+2ixt-x^2) \\ &= -\pi (t+ix)^2 + \pi x^2
\end{align*}

Substituting this expression back into the integral, we obtain $\hat{f}(x)=e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi(t+i x)^2} e^{\pi x^2} d t$.
Since the integrand is the Gaussian function $e^{-\pi (t+ix)^2}$, the integral is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$, and we have $\hat{f}(x)=e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi(t+i x)^2} e^{\pi x^2} d t=e^{-\pi x^2} \sqrt{\pi}=f(x)$.
Therefore, we have shown that $\hat{f}(x) = f(x)$, as required.

Is it correct or any suggestions?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi x^2}$? That can't be right. Your initial function was $f(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$. Notice that you have to show that, indeed, 
$$\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-\pi(t+ix)^2}dt=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\pi t^2}dt=1$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the ampersand symbol $\&$ in the displayed equation, and how can $-\pi(t+ix)^2-\pi x^2 + \pi x^2$ equal $-\pi(t+ix)^2 + \pi x^2$? The first expression is $-\pi(t+ix)^2$ and the second expression is $-\pi(t+ix)^2 + \pi x^2$, so they are equal only when $x = 0$. There must have been a typographical error in what you wrote if you didn't a computational error like that.

Comment: Your calculation, however it was meant to appear, is relying on knowledge of the Gaussian integral (whether that means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi t^2}\,dt = 1$ or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(1/2)t^2}\,dt = \sqrt{2\pi}$, which are equivalent results by a simple change of variables). But if you just set the Gaussian integral equal to an unknown value and use Fourier inversion, you'll find that the calculation you want to make is ultimately *equivalent* to the Gaussian integral calculation you want: see Section 11 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the help @KCd and @ Danka Makabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution text needs some cleanup, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(t+ix)^2}\,dt=\color{red}{1}$ is the major step here. It requires some justification (unless this "Gaussian integral" is considered "known").

The fact that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(t+ix)^2}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi z^2}\,dz$ is an application of [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) (to a rectangular contour enclosing $[-R,R]+i[0,x]$, followed by taking $R\to\infty$).

Comment: thank you for the help. makes sense now!